# Docker Desktop is not functioning as expected. Please try restarting Docker

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-5.0

I created a .net core 5 web api and planned to run using docker
with Visual studio 2019. While trying to run api in docker end up with error,

**Docker Desktop is not functioning as expected. Please try restarting Docker.**

I was not able to run the application in windows my local system.

Comment: It's not clear where you see this error, and under what conditions. Consider adding the log output where this message is displayed. It would also help to know what you've already tried.

Comment: Whats your docker version? Have you checked that whether `com.docker.service` and `Docker Desktop.exe` service are running?

Answer (score 4):

Well, I suppose you get this because your VS is not able to communicate with docker daemon which opens a net.pipe. To justify this try the below command in a command line:

`>docker run hello-world`

Regardless you have a "hello-world" container, if you get the following error: "*Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_windows: The system cannot find the file specified*".

This means you are probably missing some Windows features. Run the following command from an elevated Powershell:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All`

Then it will ask to restart your computer, then docker stuffs shall work from VS.

I had this problem recently and used [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/13075) which helped me solving the problem. Hope this helps on you too...